# Difference between these 2 CSS

Tags: css

They are the same but someone here said the positioning can affect certain functioning. It is just a flip side of both. Is it true

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css"/>
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

Comment: Nothing. Just flipped.

Comment: Have you tried it? Who said it and can you provide a source?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the attributes does not matter, like in your example they are both the same. However you should stick to the same standard so that it does not confuse you or your colleagues. So if the standard is to have href before rel, then it should be like that constantly throughout the application.

Perhaps that person meant the ordering of multiple stylesheets? The order of multiple stylesheets matters as they will overwrite identical styles in any of the stylesheets above it.

In the following example, fullcalendar.css would overwrite anything in styles.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are same. There is no difference between the two. It does not create any difference if you change the order of attributes. It depends on programmer to programmer on how they write it. But technically there is no difference.